# Setting up I2C communication between Raspberry Pi and Arduino

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, iot, i2c

I have been trying to set up I2C communication between my Raspberry Pi and two arduino pro minis using this tutorial:

https://learn.adafruit.com/adafruits-raspberry-pi-lesson-4-gpio-setup/configuring-i2c

I have done all the steps correctly, installed all the required dependencies and modified all the required files, yet "sudo i2cdetect -y 1" does not detect the arduinos. I have two PCF8591 AD/DA converter modules, and when I connect them to the RPi using the SCL and SDA ports, they are detected and shown by "sudo i2cdetect -y 1". But the arduinos do not show up. This is How I have connected the RPi and the Arduino Minis:

**RPi         -> Arduino**

3.3V        -> Vin

GND         -> GND

SDA(GPIO2)  -> SDA(A4)

SCL(GPIO3)  -> SCL(A5)

I would like to know what is going wrong here. Please suggest.

Comment: I2C bus basically has a single master and slave devices attached. Not sure how to do this but have you configured your arduino to be a slave?

Comment: Yes, I too realised this a little too late that there no difference between the RPi(master) and the Arduinos(slave) in this circuit. The Arduinos need to be configured to be used as slaves. I am studying about that, will say when I find out how this is done.

Comment: See https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MasterWriter

Comment: I studied about setting different addresses and came across these two pages:
https://oscarliang.com/raspberry-pi-arduino-connected-i2c/
https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/MasterWriter

Comment: I tried uploading the Slave Receiver Sketch from the later to the Minis, but they failed with errors. I tried uploading the sketch to UNOs, and the upload was successful. Now when I have configured the two UNOs using two different addresses, they show up on i2cdetect.

Comment: So, the doubt in this question has been solved. But it would be very convenient for my project to use the Mini Arduinos. I have opened a new thread about the problems regarding my Mini Arduinos here:
https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/29020889/Problem-uploading-sketch-and-burning-bootloader-to-Arduino-Pro-Mini.html

Please go through it and help me out if possible.